# TypeError: backward() got an unexpected keyword argument 'variables'

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, pytorch, torch

I am using the [recurrent Gaussian Process library](https://github.com/zhenwendai/RGP). I believe the code is developed by older versions of python and pytorch. I ran one of the experiments of the model after cloning the repository

```
python ./testing/rnn_rgp_test.py
```

I got this error message from [this line of the rnn_encoder.py script](https://github.com/zhenwendai/RGP/blob/master/autoreg/rnn_encoder.py#L274):

```
./RGP/autoreg/rnn_encoder.py", line 274, in backward_computation
    torch.autograd.backward( variables=self.forward_means_list + self.forward_vars_list, 
TypeError: backward() got an unexpected keyword argument 'variables'
```

I will be grateful if someone can point out how I can fix this error?

Comment: How are we supposed to answer your question without seeing the code?

Comment: @DYZ I think the answer to your question is very simple. I put a link to the repository in my question and then I posted which script I ran.

Answer (score 1):

Version [0.3.1](https://pytorch.org/docs/0.3.1/autograd.html#torch.autograd.backward) of PyTorch seems to be the last version with the `variables` parameter. Ideally, the RGP library should have documented which version of their dependencies they use but they didn't. Given that their Git repo seems to be inactive, you have several choices:

1. Use old versions of whatever libraries they require. You will have to go from one error to the next, hoping that things work as intended.
2. Fork RGP and re-implement the logic with current libraries. This will likely involve significant coding and may not even be possible at all.
3. Try to find a different library that implements RGPs.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Unfortunately this repo is the only implementation and I want to use this code. I will appreciate if you could suggest how this line should be implemented in the new version of pytorch since they used it multiple times in this library ([here](https://github.com/zhenwendai/RGP/blob/master/autoreg/rnn_encoder.py#L274)).

Comment: @Dalek you could try to remove the parameter names, i.e. `variables=` and `grad_variables=`. The meanings of these options have slightly evolved but I'm not sure the data types are still compatible.